# Visual Studio 2015 Code Coverage Wrong File

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise, and I ran a generic unit test to analyze code coverage. I am looking at the list of covered blocks per function, and they generally seem correct. However, when I right-click a method -> "Go to source code", on some functions it goes to the correct place in the source code (the relevant .cpp file), but on others it tries to open the header file (the source line number is correct, but the code is in the .cpp file--not the .h file). This affects the source code highlighting--the functions which VS thinks are in .h aren't highlighted in the .cpp. I can't determine any difference in the functions (same visibility, same header and source files), except maybe which thread they're called on. Any idea why VS thinks some code is in .h rather than .cpp?

Comment: [mcve] would help. Are you using templated functions?

Comment: I agree. No templated functions.

Comment: Is the project x64 or x86? I recall that there are issues with x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, even though VS 2015 supports the C++11 feature [non-static data member initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) (it does compile correctly), the coverage tool chokes on this feature. Here's the MCVE. I'm using VS 14.0.24720.00 Update 1. To reproduce, compile this program then get code coverage by running it using a [Generic Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182626.aspx). If `x` is initialized, the coverage tool looks for the code for the constructor in the .h file. If you take out  `= 0`, it correctly identifies the constructor definition as in the .cpp. In my product code, it wasn't the constructor, but seemingly random functions that the coverage tool thought were defined in the .h file. The fix, in my case, was just to move data member initialization to the constructor initialization list.

```
//.h
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    void Func1();

    void Func2();

    void Func3();

    int x = 0;
};
```

.

```
// .cpp
#include "Test.h"

#include <iostream>

Test::Test()
{
    std::cout << "in Test()" << std::endl;
}

Test::~Test()
{
}

void Test::Func1()
{
    std::cout << "in Func1" << std::endl;

    Func2();

    Func3();
}

void Test::Func2()
{
    std::cout << "in Func2" << std::endl;
}

void Test::Func3()
{
    std::cout << "in Func3" << std::endl;
}
```